# Date time value parsing for specific format C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

There is a string `2020-12-27 20:00:00`. An application must parse it to DateTime structure. Expected format is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.
I use:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(timeString, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time)
```

but it doesn't work. TryParseExact returns false.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hh` is 12 hours format, you should use `HH` for 24 hours

So your example becomes:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(timeString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew that it will be some lousy trifle.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `HH` instead of `hh` specifier.

[`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier) is for [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format (`00` to `23`) but [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hhSpecifier) is for [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format (`01` to `12`).

```
string s = "2020-12-27 20:00:00";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 27.12.2020 20:00:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method I wrote for purpose of converting DTs from string of any format:

```
public static DateTime? parseDate(this string date, string format = @"ddMMyyyy")
{                    
    format += "HHmmss";
    DateTime dt;            
    try 
    {
        string day = date.Substring(format.IndexOf('d'), 2);
        string month = date.Substring(format.IndexOf('M'), 2);
        string year = date.Substring(format.IndexOf('y'), 4);               
        string hour = date.Length - 1 > format.IndexOf('H')? date.Substring(format.IndexOf('H'), 2) : "00";
        string minute = date.Length - 1 > format.IndexOf('m')? date.Substring(format.IndexOf('m'), 2) : "00";
        string second = date.Length - 1 > format.IndexOf('s')? date.Substring(format.IndexOf('s'), 2) : "00";

        dt = DateTime.Parse(year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
    }
    catch { return null; }
    return dt;
}
```

Usage:

```
string date = "2014ASDA04QWER05zxc";
DateTime? dt = date.parseDate("yyyyxxxxMMxxxxdd");
```

Result: 2014/04/05 00:00

However you are right maybe you should just use `DateTime.ParseExact` with HH instead of `hh` as my method is overcomplicated for this.

Little comparison of two methods using 20 000 random dates: 
[image]

Comment: Wow.. What are this method for exactly? o.O Dividing your string with pieces is _generally_ a bad idea for parsing it to DateTime.

Comment: I had like 3 different formats of dt in string and needed to convert them to nullable datetime so i created my own extension method for this purpose :)

Comment: This is pretty useless. The code perhaps works for your situation, but it isn't reusable or internationalizable at all (hint: that `DateTime.Parse()` format won't work on pretty much any locale, people want to use other formats than that little subset this code supports). You know [`DateTime.TryParseExact` has an overload that accepts multiple formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx)? One can also opt to clean their input if the garbage characters are in fixed locations.

Comment: Ok, may be it's not the best method for the case, but it works and is ok in terms of perfomance, and i didn't try tryparse to parse dates like "2014ASDA04QWER05zxc". May be it works, may be not.